# Раскрывающееся меню JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var menuElem = document.getElementById('sweeties');
var titleElem = menuElem.querySelector('.title');

titleElem.onclick = function() {
  menuElem.classList.toggle('open');
};
```

```css
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}

.menu.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Если добавить блок с `.menu` повторно, то оно не будет раскрываться. Почему так происходит и как решить?

P.S.: вообще я предполагал, что по клику на любой из раскрывающихся списков, будут раскрываться все списки, а тут обратное.

Comment: Можно просто на CSS https://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/jaluz?q=dropdown%20menu&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте обработчик не на `id`, а на класс.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.menu > span.title');
  [].forEach.call(nodes, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      el.closest(".menu").classList.toggle("open")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}

.menu.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="sweeties2" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть id="sweeties". Идентификатор должен быть уникальным. Если Вы добавляете такое же меню с таким же идентификатором, то, разумеется, второе меню работать не будет.

Вам надо для второго меню написать другой id и в js-код также внести изменения:

```js
    var menuElem = document.getElementById('sweeties');
    var menuElem2 = document.getElementById('sweet');
    var titleElem = menuElem.querySelector('.title');
    var titleElem2 = menuElem2.querySelector('.title');

    titleElem.onclick = function() {
      menuElem.classList.toggle('open');
    };
    
    titleElem2.onclick = function() {
      menuElem2.classList.toggle('open');
    };
```

```css
.menu ul {
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
      display: none;
    }

    .menu .title {
      font-size: 18px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu .title::before {
      content: '▶ ';
      font-size: 80%;
      color: green;
    }

    .menu.open .title::before {
      content: '▼ ';
    }

    .menu.open ul {
      display: block;
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
    <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Торт</li>
      <li>Пончик</li>
      <li>Пирожное</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  
  <div id="sweet" class="menu">
    <span class="title">Сладости 2 (нажми меня)!</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Торт</li>
      <li>Пончик</li>
      <li>Пирожное</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Да, верно пишите. Только решение не элегантное. Много JS кода получается.

Comment: Я Вам просто объяснил, почему не работает и как надо сделать, чтобы работало )) Вы можете переписать этот код более элегантно.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Переписать код более элегантно - я только за, но в какую сторону хотя-бы посмотреть(с чего начать) для решения!!! Вот в чём дело.